# how to extract a certain value from a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am **scraping** data from YAHOO and trying to pull a certain value from its data frame, using a value that is on another file.

I have managed to scrape the data and show it as a data frame. the thing is I am trying to extract a certain value from the data using another df.

this is the csv i got

```
df_earnings=pd.read_excel(r"C:Earnings to Update.xlsx",index_col=2)
stock_symbols = df_earnings.index
```

output:

```
             Date        E Time           Company Name
Stock Symbol                                                
CALM         2019-04-01  Before The Open     Cal-Maine Foods
CTRA         2019-04-01  Before The Open      Contura Energy
NVGS         2019-04-01  Before The Open  Navigator Holdings
ANGO         2019-04-02  Before The Open       AngioDynamics
LW           2019-04-02  Before The Open         Lamb Weston`
```

then I download the csv for each stock with the data from yahoo finance:

```
driver.get(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock_symbol}/history?period1=0&period2=2597263000&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d')
```

output:

```
            Open     High     Low        ...       Adj Close Volume  Stock Name
Date                                     ...                                    
1996-12-12  1.81250  1.8125  1.68750     ...       0.743409  1984400        CALM
1996-12-13  1.71875  1.8125  1.65625     ...       0.777510   996800        CALM
1996-12-16  1.81250  1.8125  1.71875     ...       0.750229   122000        CALM
1996-12-17  1.75000  1.8125  1.75000     ...       0.774094   239200        CALM
1996-12-18  1.81250  1.8125  1.75000     ...       0.791151   216400        CALM
```

my problem is here I don't know how to find the date form my data frame and extract it from the downloaded file.

now I don't want to insert a manual date like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path)
df['Stock Name'] = stock_symbol
print(df.head())

df = df.reset_index()
print(df.loc[df['Date'] == '2019-04-01'])
```

output:

```
     Date        Open       High   ...  Adj Close  Volume  Stock Name
5610 2019-04-01  46.700001  47.0   ...  42.987827  846900  CALM
```

I want a condition that will run my data frame for each stock and pull the date needed

```
print(df.loc[df['Date'] == the date that is next to the symbol that i just downloaded the file for])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could make use of a variable to hold the date.

```
for sy in stock_symbols:
    # The value from the 'Date' column in df_earnings
    dt = df_earnings.loc[df_earnings.index == sy, 'Date'][sy]

    # From the second block of your code relating to 'manual' date
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_path)
    df['Stock Name'] = sy
    df = df.reset_index()
    print(df.loc[df['Date'] == dt])
```